# avoid R to simplify array into a matrix when subsetting

Tags: r

I'm subsetting different arrays which sometimes take dimension `(x,y=1,z)`. In these cases `R` automatically converts the array into a matrix and I would like to avoid it if possible keeping the structure `(x, y, z')`.

Here's an example:

```
a = array(rnorm(2*1*10), c(2,1,10)) # a is an array
b = a[,,3:5] # b is a matrix
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `drop=FALSE`

```
a[,,3:5, drop=FALSE]
```

Comment: @AP13 Thank you for the comments